# Chaging Time zone in iOS device not reflection in my application immediatly in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my app, I need to change the time formate-based on the time zone.  I am changing the time zone in settings app of the iOS, my app is not changing  time format. I need to quit app and relaunch to see change and changing Hour time(24 to 12-hour format) also not effecting even after relaunching the app.

Below is the code I am using to  in Xamarin.forms project

if (_completedDateTime != null) {
                    DateTime localTime = _completedDateTime.ToLocalTime ();

```
                string[] dateTimeList = localTime.ToString ().Split (' ');
                CompletedDateTimeString = "";

                //below logic Adding ','  to separate date and time  for showing UI
                bool isCommaAdded = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < dateTimeList.Count (); i++) {

                    if (i > 0 && !isCommaAdded) {

                        isCommaAdded = true;
                        CompletedDateTimeString += ", ";
                        CompletedDateTimeString += dateTimeList [i];
                        CompletedDateTimeString += " ";

                    } else {
                        CompletedDateTimeString += dateTimeList [i];
                    }
                }
            }
```